# Fancybox ignores thumbs option

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I got a gallery preview of five thumbnails, the gallery itself has even more photos. To avoid putting all to my code I placed them within an array.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="start_slides">
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb4.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="javascript:;"><img src="./thumb5.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

I would like to show thumbnails on the right side. However I don't get it why this is not working.

```
var $links = $("#start_slides a");

$links.on('click', function () {
    $.fancybox.open([
    { src: 'photo1.jpg', opts: { caption: 'First caption' } },
    { src: 'photo2.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Second caption' } },
    { src: 'photo3.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Third caption' } },
    { src: 'photo4.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Fourth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo5.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Fifth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo6.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Sixth caption' } },
    { src: 'photo7.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Seventh caption' } },
    { src: 'photo8.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Eigth caption' } }],
    {
        loop: true,
        thumbs: {
            autoStart: true,
            axis: "y"
        }
    }, $links.index(this)
    );
});
```

Why is this not working, how can I fix it?

Comment: Whre is your demo?

Comment: @vadivela I have no live demo, because the code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Janis answer doesn't work, but helped me finding a solution. (So thank you anyway) :-)

A thumb has to be added inside the options of each image.

```
  var $links = $("#start_slides a");

  $links.on('click', function () {
      $.fancybox.open([
      { src: 'photo1.jpg', opts: { caption: 'First caption', thumb: 'thumb1.jpg' } },
      { src: 'photo2.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Second caption', thumb: 'thumb2.jpg' } },
      { src: 'photo3.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Third caption', thumb: 'thumb3.jpg' } },
      { src: 'photo4.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Fourth caption', thumb: 'thumb4.jpg' } },
      { src: 'photo5.jpg', opts: { caption: 'Eigth caption', thumb: 'thumb5.jpg' } }],
      {
          loop: true,
          thumbs: {
              autoStart: true,
              axis: "y"
          }
      }, $links.index(this)
      );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have provided any value for thumbnail.

Replace

`{ src: 'photo1.jpg', opts: { caption: 'First caption' } }`

with

`{ src: 'photo1.jpg', thumb: 'thumb1.jpg', opts: { caption: 'First caption' } }`

and so on for the rest of items.